# C# MVC FindPartialView cannot find the path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4.I am trying to get the html string view.

```
ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
```

I am putting viewname as "create".But the return to  viewResult is view is null and showing SearchedLocartion also like,

```
~/Views/LWWApplication/Create.aspx
~/Views/LWWApplication/Create.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Create.aspx
~/Views/LWWApplication/Create.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Create.cshtml
```

Actually the forth one is the file (~/Views/LWWApplication/Create.cshtml).but return like not found.View and controller contains same folder structure.

Please Help.

Comment: Where are you calling `FindPartialView`? If from your controller, why will `PartialView(viewName)` not work?

Answer (score 19):

Try this, it is working in `MVC3`

`ViewName` should contain whole path like `~/Views/Shared/_Create.cshtml`

```
 ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
```

Answer (score 6):

Provide the full location of the partial to be rendered:

```
var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, "~/Areas/AreaName/Views/Preferences/Email.cshtml");
```